# Search and Replace with Wild Card

Tags: vi

I have a text as below -

```
xA0
xA1
xB0
xB1
```

I would like to replace this to

```
(xA 0)
(xA 1)
(xB 0)
(xB 1)
```

How to use the wildcards in this case?
Could someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does: `s/\(x[AB]\)\([01]\)/(\1 \2)/` give you the expected result?

---

## Explinations

The general pattern of search and replace is `s/pattern/replacement/`. Here the first match is `x[AB]`. Meaning that we want an `x` followed by an `A` or a `B`. Using `\( \)` to group the match and store the result in `\1`. The same is done to the number, which was assumed to be `0` or `1`. Finally refer back to the stored groups by `\1`, `\2` and put it within brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If the text is always the same length you could a substring.

Select Substring(Column, 1, 2) + ' ' + Substring(Column, 3, 1)

If you have a value of variable length though a substring won't work.